# Having problems with Python interpreter in VSCode

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code, anaconda

I've read so many articles and questions about setting Python interpreter in VSCode, but none of them helped solve my problem.

conda list:

[image: conda list]

conda info:

[image: conda info]

I activated conda env and had requests module, but my vscode keep having import error saying "ImportError: No module named requests"

```
# -*- coding: utf8 -*-
import requests

s = requests.Session()
r = s.get('https://www.naver.com') #PUT(FETCH), DELETE, GET, POST
print('1',r.text)
```

I believe that I set Python interpreter properly. However I guess VSCode can't read anaconda envs which is Python 3.5.5 but read python 2.7 that basically comes with Mac OS.

setting python interpreter:

[image: setting python interpreter]

to be short,

I selected anaconda env(section2 python3.5.5) as a interpreter and activated that env in terminal.
Although VSCode shows an interpreter(section2 python3.5.5) which I activated, when I checked sys.version it showed python 2.7.14.
Atom editor has no problem but only VSCode not working..

as I'm more familiar with VSCode I want to fix it.

Anyone know how I can solve it?

Thank you.